# Can I still use firebase's features & firestore database, if my app has been suspended from Google Play?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-play

So, what actually happened is that, I had an app named X on Google play. It was getting around 400 downloads everyday and it was just 3.5 months from its launch when Google suspended it due to some policy violation.

The app X was getting very popular among the users. So the users started to demand the app again. Therefore what I thought is I should distribute it using some other medium or maybe create own website for the app.

And here is the main question. My app was using in-app purchases and also some firebase features. Now I would have to implement some other type of payment gateway and will also need a server. And my app is already on Firebase. So, its the best option for me to use it. But, I am little afraid, that if I keep using firebase, will it be safe ? Are there any chances that Google will close my firebase project as well ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is safe to keep using firebase as your app violated the policy of Google Play not your firebase project and as you told you are thinking to distribute your app through website so it's totally safe. Also if it makes you feel any better my app was also suspended from Google Play but i can still use my firebase project & it's related services.